# Slanted slash, angle control

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-shapes

How can I achieve this angled slash (/) using CSS? It should be responsive and should also have IE 8 support?

[image: Slanted slash]

Comment: Please Edit your question,is not quite clear.

Comment: Added the CSS-shapes tag for better categorization, moved the description to the top and removed the "using CSS" from title because CSS is already present as a tag. Coming to the question, while posting code is not always mandatory for a question, it is always better to indicate if you have tried anything and if yes, what problems you had faced with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an element and hide the unwanted parts with pseudo elements and borders (which are supported by IE8):

```css
div{
    position:relative;
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
    background: #000;
}
div:before, div:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
}
div:before{
    top: 0; left: 0;
    border-left: 99px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 99px solid transparent;
}
div:after{
    bottom: 0; right: 0;
    border-right: 99px solid #fff;
    border-top: 99px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

You can control the slant by changing the border widths on the pseudo elements. For an explanation of how this works, see here: [How do CSS triangles work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work)

Although this can't be implemented over an image or gradient because of the plain color triangles, It can be [responsive](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/0xgmbx1L/1/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CSS for creating a content,
You must use the CSS content property
and you must apply it to CSS property with ::before selector.
Here is the example

```css
.number::before {content:"\2215"}
```

```html
<span class="number">12</span>
```

The only difference is,you must use `::before` with one semicolon for IE8 `:before`

IE8 Supports both the [CSS :before Pseudo selector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc304078(v=vs.85).aspx),and [CSS content property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp).

For the content property,you need to find the specific "slash" that you want,in the Unicode table

Comment: IE8 [only supports the CSS 2.1 syntax](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent) with one semicolon for pseudo elements

Comment: @web-tiki,Thanks A Lot